# Zend Routing not working correctly

Tags: zend-framework

I have a Zend app which I am trying to port over to a [new] computer. I have it working already on the previous machine.

When I go to the URL localhost/myapp, the application loads the correct index page (i.e. runs my IndexController.indexAction() as it should). However, when I go to any other page, I get an error that the controller "myapp" cannot be found.

I have confirmed that rewrites are working (the error page that is rendered is via my custom ErrorController) - it seems that for some reason, Zend is treating the webroot as localhost, which means that the first parameter after that, "myapp", is being treated as the controller.

Any ideas as to what might cause this, and how to fix it without moving the entire application into the root of the web directory?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with the addition of the following line in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /myapp
```

I'm not quite sure why this line is needed (it's completely omitted on the original computer where the application works just fine), but adding it in solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was working because your .htaccess file is at the root directory so by localhost/myapp it was going to its index.php but couldnt find .htaccess in the project's folder

Comment: Actually, not. On the other computer, this line was omitted, but I also had several Zend apps each in its own sub-directory of the server root.